# Play store apps downloading forever after factory reset

Tags: google-play-store, rooting, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, installation, tablet

Steps before the problems :

1. The tablet was inactive, whitout recharging, for arround 1 year and
   half.
2. Acidentaly pressed the keys to 'Download a custom os', and restarted the tablet during the process of download depsite the warning saying i shouldn't.
3. Did a factory reset trough the config option.

The problems :

1. All apps from playstore cant be updated or installed. When clicked on install, it will be 'installing' forever.
2. Cant install apk from outside playstore, i get a messsage  "There is a problem with the analisys of the package" (translated freely from my language). Tried 3 apks so far.
3. The time is wrong, 1h fowrward, maybe due to summertime.

solutions i tried :

- For the problem 1 : Clear the cache and the data of the playstore, the download manager and gmail and forced them to stop (in a lot of diferent orders); Logged out and in the email on playstore (with diferent emails); checked for system updates (had none); checked if internal storage was fine downloading several thing from browser, all downloaded and executed normaly; Tried other apps, working pefectly(one, a store, even updated itself, but i couldnt install its apps as well; Restarted ; did another(s) factory reset; and changed the time manually.
- For the problem 2 i just tried to find apk to android 4.0, and im not shure i did it ok.
- For the problem 3 i changed the time manually; automatically; selected the region manually and automatcally, rebooted ; and just used the tablet for 2 days to see if would change. Did those repeatedly in various diferent orders.

Nothing worked, for any poblem. The youtube says, when i open it, that i have either the datetime wrong or a bad internet conection, even when i put the right time manually. So i think the time maybe could be causing the playstore problem also ? I dont know. Im tired.

info :

- Tablet samsung p5100
- Android 4.03
- hardware has arround 7 years old
- Touchscreen broken once, replaced in the past.
- no sd card
- The device might be rooted, cant tell, because cant install root checkers (it had the app supersu installed even after the factory reset. I removed it from an option inside the own app and it dosent persists factory resets anymore. Its gone)

Ps: there is no google play services installed, at least not with this name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the problem 2 : Just install an valid apk for your current  android versions, in my case, 4.0.3

Solution to the problem 1 : Download and install (using the browser) a new playstore apk for your android version from another trusted store/site, like 'apkmirror'.